# Spring data @Formula count query

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm trying to use count query inside the @Formula (Spring boot app)

```
@Formula("select count(te.id) from task_execution te")
```

however when starting server, getting exception

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:

says I have syntax error in query and following query printed in log:

```
select count(te.id) from task_execution te as formula6_ from node_info nodeinfo0
```

my question where this `from node_info nodeinfo0` came from? My NodeInfo class is not related to TaskExecution class in any way

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to put the expression into braces. The error was very misleading.